# Maximizing volume of a rectangular solid, given surface area, and one dimension is twice the size of another dimension.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am taking Calc 1 in university at the moment and was given this question:

**Find the dimensions of the largest and closed rectangular box with a surface area of 100 cm^2, given that one dimension is twice as large as another dimension.**

I understand how to find the max volume with a given surface area, but the part about one dimension being twice as large as another dimension is throwing me off. I have this so far...

**V=lwh**

**SA=2(lw+hl+hw)=100cm^2**

If one dimension is twice as large as another dimension, I could say l=2w.Then...

**SA=4w^2+4wh+2wh=100**

**h= (50-2w^2)/3w**

I plugged that h into the volume formula, what is next??

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

After plugging $h$ in, you get that the Volume =$2 w^2h$ which can be expressed as a function  of one single independent variable $w$ only.

$$ Vol = 2 w^2\, h$$
$$ h= \frac23\cdot \dfrac{25-w^2}{w} $$
Ignore constants and yes, now differentiate, equate D.C. to zero using chain rule on
$$ w\cdot (25-w^2)$$

$$ \frac{25-w^2}{w} = -\frac{-2w}{1}$$

getting

$$ w= \frac{5}{\sqrt 3},$$

so the sides are

$$ (l,w,h)=(10,5,20/3)/{\sqrt 3} $$

Comment: After getting the function with the independent variable "w", do I find the derivative and set it equal to zero to find the critical points, which would be the value of w?